# I need some help I try to run command update-database in API project with ASP.NET and I got this errorr

Tags: c#, api, rest

[image]

**this is my DbContext**

[image]

**and this what I got as a error**

Answer (score 0):

Open the Package Manager Console from Tools → Library Package Manager → Package Manager Console and then run the enable-migrations command (make sure that the default project is the project where your context class is).

Also your db connection strings should be in your config file like the warning says